# Counting with skipping some dates, with Ms Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, counting

I`m looking for possibility to count some rows in my table.
I have a table with some Columns like: Names  Costs  Quantity  Date 
This date is date of 1st month sales.
There are thousands of products.
This tables has 45.000 queries

its looks

```
Name      Costs  Quantity   Date
ProductA  1250   45         01/03/2011
ProductA  1250   23         01/06/2011
ProductB  750    31         01/02/2011
ProductB  750    45         01/09/2011
ProductB  750    21         01/12/2011
ProductB  750    45         01/01/2012
ProductB  750    37         01/03/2012
ProductB  750    25         01/06/2013
ProductB  750    11         01/07/2014
ProductB  750    15         01/09/2014
```

I would like to build queries which will be able to count Date and continue counting after 1st month of the sales, the next count will count not visible information and only will show counting Cycle for the some of specified information.

I will give a name for this column like "Month Live"

It will be look like that after this queries/question like that

```
Name      Costs  Quantity   Date         Month Live
ProductA  1250   45         01/03/2011   1
ProductA  1250   23         01/06/2011   4
ProductB  750    31         01/02/2011   1
ProductB  750    45         01/09/2011   8
ProductB  750    21         01/12/2011   11
ProductB  750    45         01/01/2012   12
ProductB  750    37         01/03/2012   14
ProductB  750    25         01/06/2013   29
ProductB  750    11         01/07/2014   41
ProductB  750    15         01/09/2014   43
```

How to execute to get the result like this one ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [edit] your question to better explain how those [Month Live] values have been derived.

Comment: Why has this been put on hold when my answer, it seems to me, actually gets the desired result? Try it out for yourselves if you don't believe me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to make assumptions:

- The table is called `ProductCosts`
- The month counting is relative to the product only, not product + costs (since no product is shown with different costs for different dates in your sample data, this point is ambiguous). My suggested code can be tweaked easily enough if that is not the case however.
- You haven't counted the months correctly for the last two rows in your sample output

Given all that...

```
SELECT t.Name, t.Costs, t.Quantity, t.Date, DateDiff("m", s.FirstDate, t.Date) + 1 AS MonthLive
FROM ProductCosts t
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT m.Name, MIN(m.Date) AS FirstDate
        FROM ProductCosts m
        GROUP BY m.Name) s
    ON t.Name = s.Name
ORDER BY t.Name, t.Date
```